# Update Galaxy Nexus from 4.2.2 to 4.3 while keeping files and root

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a rooted GNex with stock kernel and stock ROM. Device is only rooted, CWM installed and unlocked bootloader.

I received the OTA update yesterday but haven't tried to apply it since I have a custom recovery installed. You should also know that I removed a file called recovery-from-boot.p to avoid the stock recovery from getting reflashed following the indications in this thread http://www.droidforums.net/forum/galaxy-nexus-development/189062-using-rom-manager-only-way-boot-into-clockwork-mod-recovery.html

I'd like to apply the OTA without losing my data and possibly not root. Losing root is not such a big problem but if you know a way of installing the 4.3 update from CWM without losing data then I'd be so thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't lose any data by flashing the OTA file. You can flash the ota file (see [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/26/how-to-flash-your-galaxy-nexus-takju-or-yakju-to-android-4-3-jwr66v-and-root-it-right-now/) for info and where to download it from) and as long as you've not changed any system files it should apply ok. Simply select the "apply update from sdcard" option and select the update file. You will lose root but you can simply flash [SuperSu](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113517319477420052449/posts/7o5H214hRSv) (the only superuser app that works on 4.3 at the moment) which will "re-root" your device. If you get a prompt about disabling recovery flash, select "No" as the new SuperSu uses this part of getting root access.

Comment: thanks a lot, just a few questions, should I select install from zip in CWM and then find the OTA that was downloaded to my phone or should I manually download the 4.3 update from Google and put it on the root of my sd? Also, when it's done applying the update should I then install the SuperSU.zip in CWM or first reboot the phone? Or is it better to flash SuperSU from my pc? Sorry for all the questions but I'm not that good at this, almost bricked my old Sony Xperia Ray once :S

Comment: I'd suggest downloading it from [Google](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_maguro/6c7ff815e7762f651ad6f8c74e5cb281093f1e0b.signed-yakju-JWR66V-from-JDQ39.6c7ff815.zip) as then you know exactly where it is.  You can flash SuperSU straight away, no need to reboot. If you get a prompt about disabling recovery flash, select "No" as the new SuperSu uses this part of getting root access.

Comment: Btw, the only system file I've changed is the "recovery-from-boot.p" file which I deleted, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, one last question, over at XDA I was told "Just remember to tell CWM to NOT fix the stock recovery flashing. Like I said, superSU will do that for you." I asked for clarifications yesterday but nobody has answered, do you know what he meant?

Comment: I think that should be ok. I just edited my previous post as i provided the wrong link. [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/26/how-to-flash-your-galaxy-nexus-takju-or-yakju-to-android-4-3-jwr66v-and-root-it-right-now/) has a guide which contains links for a couple of variants of the Galaxy Nexus (i've linked to the international variant without Google Wallet)

Comment: The stock rom includes a install-recovery.sh file which flashes the stock recovery. The new SuperSU uses this file to provide superuser access, so CWM will offer to disable this. You need to choose "No" so that it doesn't delete this file. If you forget you can simply flash SuperSU again and it'll put it back in.

Comment: Just wanted to tell you that the whole process went fine, but I did a nandroid backup first just to be safe ;) The phone seemed a bit confused at first, as the OTA Update Available icon remained in the notifications bar for a few minutes. Thanks again for your help :)